# Doctrine / Symfony Joining tables: unexpected behavior

Tags: join, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am trying to achieve some efficiency gains by having several records joined from several tables in accordance to the article: [Joining to Related Records](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#joining-to-related-records). In my model, I have a Tracker that has one Linkset, which in turn has multiple Links. Now, in my Controller I want to loop through those links via:

```
foreach ($tracker->getLinkset()->getLinks() as $link) etc..
```

Moreover, the code in my Tracker repository is as follows:

```
public function findWithLinks(Tracker $tracker)
{
      $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
                    ->select('t, ls, l')
                    ->innerJoin('t.linkset', 'ls')
                    ->leftJoin('ls.links', 'l')
                    ->where('t.id = :trackerId')
                    ->setParameters(array(
                          'trackerId' => $tracker->getId()
                    ));

      return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

What I would expect is, in the controller, when I loop through the foreach table, that Symfony does not make any additional calls to the database, because I have a Tracker with joined linkset and joined links. However, two additional queries are run to get the Linkset and the Links separately. Here are the mappings of the associated entities:

**The Linkset entity:**

```
/**
  * @var Link
  *
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Link", mappedBy="linkset")
  */
  private $links;
```

**The Link entity**

```
/**
  * @var Linkset
  *
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Linkset", inversedBy="link")
  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="linkcombo",
  *   joinColumns={
  *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="link_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
  *   },
  *   inverseJoinColumns={
  *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="linkset_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
  *   }
  * )
  */
  private $linkset;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your "foreach" statement to something like this?

```
foreach( $tracker->getLinkset() as $linkset ) {
    foreach( $linkset->getLinks() as $link ) {
        ....
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

**Edit**:

If the relation between "linkset" and "link" is just a manytomany relation, I would change the annotations to look like this:

*The linkset entity*:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Link")
 **/
private $links;
```

*The Link entity*:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Linkset")
 */
```

This shall work assuming that:

- Both Link and Linkset entities share the same namespace, otherwise you should change the targetEntity="XXX" to be fully qualified (i.e.: Your\Bundle\Entities\Linkset and Your\OtherBundle\Entities\Link
- The relation between Tracker and Linkset is OK (did you checked that?)

I'm sure someone more experienced with symfony2 might help you better than me, I've started recently using symfony

Comment: alghimo, thanks for your reply, but unfortunately that does not seem to work. It is kind of confusing, since the article at the Symfony website suggests that it should work. I must be overlooking something! :-(

Comment: sorry, I didn't took a look at your entities, I saw quite clear the foreach was the problem. I'll edit my comment with another suggestion

Comment: Hi Alghimo, thanks for your response and your effort. But this is not working either. If I remove the 'mappedBy="linkset"' notion, then Symfony2 complains that this particular attribute is not present. Any other ideas?